# failed to integrate new admob google play version interstitial

Tags: android, admob

I have added google play service lib in my project, after that I added meta-data and activity of admob in manifest file. Then I added a code for interstitial in main activity and call displayinterstitial() also but still it is not showing an ad. What is missing in these steps? below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);


    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("APPID");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Car Shop");
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {.................}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    displayInterstitial();
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly do **NOT** call displayInterstitial from #onAdLoaded. This will generate an extremeley poor user experience as the ad will show at some indeterminate point. Instead call displayInterstitial at a natural break point in your app.

Other than that, what you have shown of your code looks fine. Have a look in the logs, it probably has an message in there saying that there are no ads available.

Comment: I edited my code with reference to "https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced". please have a look. still not showing ad.

Comment: If there is no ad related log messages then you never called interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: how can i call this? will u help me for that?

Comment: i am beginner in android. please can you post code for this?

Comment: I did like this. Is this right or wrong?
public void displayInterstitial() {
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {

   interstitial.show();
  }
 
 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdLoaded(){
             displayInterstitial();
        }
});}

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. Get rid of the AdListener, you don't need it. Just call displayInterstitial at a natural break in your app.

Comment: i tried a lot, but couldn't make it possible. :( can you write a code for me? please as i am a beginner in android.

Comment: You've already written all the code you need. You just need to decide where/when to call displayInterstitial. And that depends entirely upon the flow of your app.

Comment: i just call displayinterstitial and update my code. Please have a look.

Comment: So your code looks fine, thought I probably wouldn't call displayInterstitial from onTabSelected(). You must be getting Admob log at runtime. So if you are still not getting ads look at the log.

Comment: I just checked but there is nothing showing in logcat. I also checked by putting it in OnBackPressed(). But still the same.

Comment: ya i m done. i just had to create new id for full page ad. thanx a lot for ur help. :)